conflict betwen 2 php codes, using the metaslider plugin
I have this 2 code snippets for the WordPress plugin metaslider. The first one adds the "ken burns effect", the second one disables the "pause on action" property. For some reason, the "pause on action" is messing the "ken burns effect" after some seconds,  ¿What could be the problem? THANKS!
THE FIRST CODE
$slideshow_id = '33';

add_filter('metaslider_css_classes', function($classes, $id) use ($slideshow_id) {
    if ($id != $slideshow_id) return $classes;
    return $classes . ' kenburns-effect';
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('metaslider_css', function($css, $settings, $id) use ($slideshow_id) {
    if ($id != $slideshow_id) return $css;
    return $css . "
    .kenburns-effect .flexslider .slides,
    .kenburns-effect .flexslider .slides > li {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .kenburns-effect .flexslider .slides > li .kenburns-inner {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .kenburns-effect .flexslider .slides img {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .kenburns-effect .flexslider .slides > li.flex-active-slide .kenburns-inner {
        animation: kb-zoom-out {$settings['delay']}ms;  
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes kb-zoom-out {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.3);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }";
}, 10, 3);

add_filter('metaslider_flex_slider_list_item_attributes', function($attributes, $slide, $id) use ($slideshow_id) {
    if ($id != $slideshow_id) return $attributes;
    $movements = ['center left', 'center center', 'center right', 'top left', 'top center', 'top right', 'bottom left', 'bottom center', 'bottom right'];
    $attributes['data-background'] = isset($slide['src']) ? $slide['src'] : '';
    $attributes['data-movement'] = $movements[array_rand($movements)];
    return $attributes;
}, 10, 3);

add_filter('metaslider_flex_slider_javascript', function($js, $id) use ($slideshow_id) {
    if ($id != $slideshow_id) return $js;
    return $js . ";window.jQuery('.kenburns-effect .slides .ms-image').each(function() {
        var background = $(this).data('background');
        var movement = $(this).data('movement');
        $(this).prepend(\"<div class='kenburns-inner' style='background-image:url(\" + background + \");transform-origin:\" + movement + \"'></div>\");
    });";
}, 10, 2);

THE SECOND CODE
function custom_metaslider_js() {

    $slideshow_id = '33';

    $js = "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.metaslider-{$slideshow_id}').flexslider({
                pauseOnAction: false
            });
        });
    </script>
    ";
    echo $js;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_metaslider_js');


I just solved it, modifying the "pause on action code" this way, the wright way:


function metaslider_flex_params($options, $slider_id, $settings) {
    if ($slider_id == 33) { // check for slider ID (optional)
        $options['pauseOnAction'] = "false"; // pauseOnAction }
    } 
    return $options;
} 
add_filter('metaslider_flex_slider_parameters', 'metaslider_flex_params', 10, 3);



